# modrewrite of url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have some mod rewrite which will remove the .php and format a certain page called county.php.

My problem is with the part that rewrites the county.php. I have to put a '/' in front of all the links to css, images and js files. This causes problems on other parts of the site as I use php includes. Is there away around this? Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^county/([^/\.]+)/?$ county.php?county_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)$ county.php?county_id=$1

Comment: still have to put a / in front of the css and other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mod_rewrite to create virtual folders you have to deal with different folder names for all additional media types (CSS, JS, images ...). To deal with a dynamic number of folders or even some pages with folders and some without makes it more complicated.

I see following ways to solve that:

1. use always the same number of folders (folder depth) - or
2. do not use / character for separating parameters (e.g. "county_xzy") - or
3. create mod_rewrite rules for your media files as well

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*/(.*?)\.css$ css/$1.css
RewriteRule .*/(.*?)\.js$ js/$1.js
RewriteRule .*/(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ images/$1.$2
RewriteRule ^county/([^/\.]+)/?$ county.php?county_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
```